# Most idiomatic way to provide default value in python?

Tags: python

Many discussions and SO searches have been unable to conclusively answer the question of the best/safest/most Pythonic way of providing a default value if a Python function receives `None` in a parameter. This specifically came up in regards to a `datetime` parameter, in case that matters, but ideally we standardize our approach for all parameter types.

Here are the two approaches that *both* keep coming up as the "correct" way to do this:

1. `myval if myval else defaultval`
2. `myval or defaultval`

Are they both functionally equivalent, or are there subtle differences between the two? I vastly prefer the brevity and clarity of the second option, but adherents to the first one say it's not always safe. Any guidance from someone with more python experience than me (e.g. nearly anyone) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 is by far the preffered method of conditional assignment  (Explicit is better than implicit)

and even better to be explicit

```
myval = myval if myval is not None else defaultval
```

or even better

```
def some_function(arg1,arg2="defaultValue"):
    myval = arg2
```

the main problem is

```
x = x or y
```

can never be assigned an x of 0 or an empty array or any other falsy value

Comment: Well, for one, consider the case of a object type where one of its possible values would be considered ``False``, for instance an int. Option one allows you to be more explisit on what conditions you want the default value and what conditions you want the user provided value.

Comment: The function version does not protect against `some_function(val1, None)`.

Comment: well then its an explicit value of None that is supplied ... why would it give you a default instead? that would require some more processing\

Comment: @aruisdante OP's option one does no such thing however, it just checks `myval` rather than `myval is not None` or such.

Comment: Yeah, my comment was in response to a comment the OP made and then deleted. I'd note that one flaw in your function default value is that default values in methods are only evaluated once, at parse-time. This doesn't matter for an immutable type like a string or number, but for a mutable type like a date time or a list, can result in very unexpected behavior if you mutate the default value (it will persist across calls). For mutable types you should always default them to none, then assign them to a default value inside the method body.

Comment: heh yeah thats why I used a string in the example :P

Comment: I think the point that x cannot be assigned zero is reason enough to avoid option 2 in the general case. Thanks. (FYI @aruisdante I didn't make and delete a comment.)

Comment: I've accepted this answer but per @aruisdante's comment, I actually am using this code to default a blank `datetime` parameter to `datetime.utcnow()`, so I cannot use parameter default values. I will use the `myval = myval if myval is not None else defaultval` construction.

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly equivalent, however I suggest

```
defaultval if myval is None else myval
```

(This behaves properly when passed ie `myval = []`).

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), both options are semantically equivalent and you can pick the one you like:

Statement: `x or y`; Result: `if x is false, then y, else x`, and the Note:
This is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is `False`.